# Platform-independent normalization of unicode usernames

Tags: python, web-services, unicode, unicode-normalization

In [a semi-recent bug disclosure](http://labs.spotify.com/2013/06/18/creative-usernames/), spotify talks about how users used a glitch in the username normalization code to gain access to accounts which they did not own. The problem was that they were applying a non-idempotent operation to the usernames to check if they were taken, so ᴮᴵᴳᴮᴵᴿᴰ and BIGBIRD were separate usernames when they shouldn't be.

I would like to allow Unicode usernames for my web site, but I do not want to be vulnerable to these kind of attacks. I do not use Python, so I cannot use the solution they proposed on their website. Is there any kind of idempotent formula, that can be used on any platform (i.e. python, ruby, lua, javascript, .NET, etc) supporting Unicode operations, which will treat two Unicode strings that have only "visual" differences the same string? Is it as simple as NKFD + lowercasing the string?

Comment: The basic advice is that you have one single point of entry for all your string input, and that you always use that and never mangle strings again once they've entered your system. So both the user generation and the username availability check would be processed the same, however that is.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, but I still don't know how to make sure that ᴮᴵᴳᴮᴵᴿᴰ and BIGBIRD and BigBird and bigbird and βιgвιяδ are all the same username.

Comment: Try iconv/transliterate maybe? That's a really vague requirement, though... I'd just leave it at Unicode normalization (which your example isn't).

Comment: NKFD + uppercase (not lowercase) will take care of ᴮᴵᴳᴮᴵᴿᴰ and BIGBIRD and BigBird and bigbird. βιgвιяδ is a different, it is visual spoofing, and nothing will be 100% reliable. But you can take a look at http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/SpoofChecker.html

Comment: Ideally, you should casefold instead of uppercasing or lowercasing. I'd also recommend NFKC instead of NFKD, since NFC is the default for web content.